# Movie where babysitter gets electrocuted in the kitchen

Tags: identify-this-movie

Sorry, I don't have many details to go on for this one, but I recall watching a movie on TV during my childhood (i.e. 1993-2000) where a young, pretty babysitter is in the kitchen and the floor somehow got filled up with water (I seem to remember it being soapy water) and something happened to expose the water to electricity. I can't remember exactly what, but the babysitter died from the electric shock. Other details include:

- The movie was live-action (i.e. *not* animated).
- There is a good chance the movie was made in the 80's (I've always liked older movies).
- I have no idea what genre the movie was, but most likely was either comedy or horror as those have always been my favorite types of movies.
- It would have been an American made movie, and was most likely aired on one of the public TV stations such as USA, Sci-Fi Channel, TNT, or one of the other similar stations.
- I'm really not sure on this, but I believe she may have been listening to music on her headphones while this happened.

My first thought was [Don't Tell Mom the Babysitter's Dead](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101757/), but after looking up the plot description, the babysitter just doesn't match. It was definitely a young girl, and she definitely died in the kitchen from electrocution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from [Ghost in the Machine (1993)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Machine_%28film%29#Plot):

> Karl opens the scanned page from Terry's address-book and begins killing the names that are on her list. Her co-worker, Frank Mallory (Richard McKenzie), becomes the first victim when he dies in an electrical fire. Another friend, Elliot Kastner (Jack Laufer) gets burned to death when a hand-dryer turns into a flame-thrower. Terry's babysitter, Carol Maibaum (Shevonne Durkin), becomes the third victim when she gets caught between an exploding TV-set and a dishwasher in her kitchen.

You can watch most of the scene in this [odd mash-up on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB5Nn--X2g4).

Comment: That was it! As soon as I saw her outfit I recognized her.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same scene in my head. The movie is ["The Believers"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092632/) from 1987

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure this isn't the right answer.